# How do I make a button?

Tags: java, swing, button, actionlistener

I don't want a `JButton` or anything like that, I am having trouble figuring out `ActionListener`s.
If someone could tell me what should I add to his code, so when I click at these coordinates it takes me to the next state:

```
class paint extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

  public void MouseInput(MouseEvent m){

    int y = m.getY();
    int x = m.getX();

    if(x >= 250 && x <= 550 && y >= 300 && y <= 400){

    }
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  }
}
```

Comment: For a JPanel to respond to mouse clicks, you need to add a MouseListener to the panel. Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html. Buttons can have ActionListeners because they translate low-level mouse clicks and keyboard actions into higher-level action events. JPanels don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have your Swing component `JPanel` notified about some source **events**, in your case you want to listen to the **mouse clicks**; you component should add some listener that implements the `MouseListener` (This listener should implement the methods declared in the `MouseListener` interface and which will underly your custom logic though):

```
public class MyMouseListener implements MouseListener
{
  @Override
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
  {
    // How click event should be handled 
  }

  @Override
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
  {
    // How press (clicked but not released) event should be handled 
  }

  @Override
  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
  {
    // How release mouse button event should be handled 
  }

  @Override
  public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
  {
    // How mouse cursor enter event should be handled 
  }

  @Override
  public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
  {
    // How mouse cursor exit event should be handled 
  }
}
```

Then your `JPanel` component can add this lisneter:

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    MyPanel panel = new MyPanel();
    panel.addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener());
  }
}
```

The default approach is to declare the `MouseListener` specific implementation as an inner Class of the Swing component in order to benefit of natural bind of those classes and gain access to both instance variables from one and the other. 
This will let you have multiple listeners for a single event but you still can make your own component the listener if such is not your need:

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    MyPanel panel = new MyPanel();
    panel.initialize();
  }

  private void initialize()
  {
    this.addMouseListener(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
  {
  }

  @Override
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
  {
  }

  @Override
  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
  {
  }

  @Override
  public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
  {
  }

  @Override
  public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
  {
  }
}
```